Scrollbar issue and automatic time selection issue in Antd Datepicker(showTime)
I have added datepicker of antd in antd form and added disabledTime props and added props value to disabled the future time from current when today's date is selected, but because i think it checking time at every second my scrollbar resetting automatically but in 5.0.0 and older version of antd is it working fine, and one more thing when I select today's date it is automatically selecting the current time but in the new version it is not selecting, it is showing 00:00
This is my code in react project with antd form field
            <FormItem
              name={"incident_time_1"}
              rules={[
                {
                  required: true,
                  message: "Please enter incident time",
                },
              ]}
              {...formItemLayout}
              label='Incident Date Time'
            >
              <DatePicker
                format={"YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm"}
                showTime
                disabledTime={(current) => {
                  if (!current) return {};
                  const now = dayjs();
                  if (current.isSame(now, "day")) {
                    return {
                      disabledHours: () =>
                        Array.from({ length: 24 }, (_, i) => i).filter(
                          (hour) => hour > now.hour()
                        ),
                    };
                  }
                  return {};
                }}
                disabledDate={(current) =>
                  current && current > dayjs().endOf("day")
                }
                onChange={(value) =>
                  form.setFieldsValue({ incident_time_2: value })
                }
              />
            </FormItem>

